# How to tell if Visual Studio Code extension is installed locally or globally?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do you tell if an extension is installed globally or locally?  The [VS Code Extension Marketplace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery) doesn't appear to answer this question explicitly, nor does `code --help`.  I'm guessing that if I see the extension in ~/.vscode it's global but if I only see it in node_modules (I'm writing JavaScript), it's installed locally, but I'm not sure.